# SplitView Controller Menu Overlay

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uisplitviewcontroller, uiwindow

I'm trying to create a menu overlay system on top of a split view application for the iPad. The menu overlay systems is suppose to support a few buttons, one of which will make the overlay disappear and show the SplitViewController.

My application delegate is as follows:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view addSubview:[splitViewController view]];
[view addSubview:[mainMenu view]];
[window addSubview:view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The UIViews are showing up, but in a very weird scattered manner with many interface features not responding.

Any help?

Thanks,

CSwat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. UIWindow cannot handle multiple views. You need to add one view, remove it with [myView.removeFromSuperview] when appropriate, and add the next view.